# Linear Isoperimetric Inequality is invariant under quasi isometry

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are quasi-isometric. Show that $X$ satisfies a linear isoperimetric inequality iff $Y$ satisfies a linear isoperimetric inequality.

My idea: Suppose $X$ satisfies a linear isoperimetric inequality. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ be a quasi-isometry with quasi-isometry inverse $g$. Let $c$ be a loop in $Y$. Then $g(c)$ is a loop in $X$. Then using the fact that $X$ satisfies linear isoperimetric inequality we have to show that $Y$ satisfies a linear isoperimetric inequality. 
But I can't do that.

Comment: Hints: How does the length of the loop $g(c)$ compare to the length of $c$? How can the linear isoperimetric inequality in $X$ be applied to the loop $g(c)$? ...

Comment: The word quasi isometry gets used in at least two different ways. It's a good idea to always define it.

Comment: Quasi-isometry here is a function satisfying for some $c>0$: for all $x,y\in X$, $d(f(x),f(y))\in [cd(x,y)+c,c^{-1}d(x,y)-c]$ and for all $z\in Y$, $d(z,f(X))\le c$.